# SVG with data-binding for href gets updated but doesn't display new image

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple SVG to display in my component. On a button click, the SVG will display image A or B. This is my current template:

```
<svg>
    <use [attr.xlink:href]="getIconLink()"></use>
</svg>
<div (click)="changeImageValue()"></div>
```

This is the relevant code for interactivity:

```
currentIcon = "potato"

changeImageValue() {
    if (this.currentIcon == "potato") {
        this.currentIcon = "tomato";
    } else {
        this.currentIcon = "potato";
    }
}

getIconLink(): string {
    if (this.currentIcon == "potato") {
        return "someLinkToAPotato";
    } else {
        return "someLinkToATomato";
    }
}
```

When I inspect the element in Chrome, I can see that the `href` value gets updated properly, but the rendered image stays the same as it was before. What could cause the binding to work properly, but the rendering of the SVG not reloading? Is there a way to force refresh?

I added logs in all methods and they do get called at the right times and change the values, it's just the rendering of the image that doesn't change.

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz project showing your code?

Comment: @bjdose I am working on an enterprise application. There is way too much code for me to paste here and would make my problem less obvious. I don't think there is anything wrong with my code as the href value is updated, it's just that the svg is not re-rendering. Is there a way to force the svg to re-render?

Comment: Maybe you can use changeDetectorRef for forcing the update of the DOM

Answer (score 0):

Try to force the update of the DOM using changeDetectorRef.

```js
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private _cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

changeImageValue() {
    if (this.currentIcon == "potato") {
        this.currentIcon = "tomato";
    } else {
        this.currentIcon = "potato";
    }
    this._cdr.detectChanges(); // <- force to update the DOM

}
```